# Is this caching thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, caching, guava

I'm curious whether this caching idea is guaranteed to work:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor @Getter class CacheEntry {
    static CacheEntry get(String string, int start) {
        int hash = string.hashCode() ^ start; // or something better
        int index = hash & (cache.length-1);
        CacheEntry result = cache[index];
        if (result!=null && result.matches(string, start)) return result;
        result = new CacheEntry(string, start, computeSomething(string, start));
        cache[index] = result;
        return result;
    }

    private boolean matches(String string, int start) {
        if (string.equals(this.string)) return false;
        if (start == this.start) return false;
        return true;
    }

    private static ImmutableSomething computeSomething(String string, int start) {
        ...
    }

    private static final CacheEntry[] cache = new CacheEntry[256];

    private final String string;
    private final int start;

    private final ImmutableSomething something;
}
```

The annotations come from [lombok](http://projectlombok.org). Just imagine each does what its name says.

The goal is to save calls to `computeSomething` and also to minimize allocations.

The caching is neither synchronized nor thread local. There's no guarantee that one thread will see updates done by another one. That's acceptable. Neither is there any guarantee that one thread doesn't overwrite the entries from another one. That's acceptable, too.

In a small benchmark I wrote it lead to a nice speedup when compared to [sane caching alternatives](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained). My concern is correctness: Can ever happen, that a thread sees an invalid entry (e.g., one containing a wrong `something`)?

Comment: It looks correct to me. Assigning an object reference to a variable is an atomic operation, and you don't care about the absence of memory visibility guarantee, so it looks OK (except for the obvious compilation problems).

Comment: @JBNizet Compilation problems gone. Writing anything a bit longer without IDE is a bad idea, I see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would work as long as `CacheEntry` is a proper immutable object (as opposed to a mere effectively immutable object). This is because immutable objects can be safely published without synchronisation and object reference assignment is atomic.

In other words, it wouldn't be safe if `CacheEntry` is not fully immutable, as the consumer thread may see an object that isn't fully constructed. Also, if what is cached is primitive types whose assignments aren't atomic (`double`, `long`), the consumer thread could see garbage (half assigned values).

**EDIT**:
According to [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=EK43StEVfJIC&pg=PT64&lpg=PT64&dq=java%20concurrency%20in%20practice%20immutable%20object&source=bl&ots=uoUxD2yQlw&sig=7ZzT-gyHLTstKxJyd5TJvKVsFcg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=v9sVVN_eAdDsaOnigsAG&ved=0CF8Q6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=java%20concurrency%20in%20practice%20immutable%20object&f=false), an object can be safely published without synchronization if:

- Its state cannot be modified after construction
- All its fields are declared `final`
- It is properly constructed (the `this` keyword does not escape during construction)

Comment: I guess, by "effectively immutable" you mean things like `Collections.unmodifiable...`, right?

Comment: Do you think that a `final long` field in `CacheEntry` or in `ImmutableSomething` could be a problem? I hope no, because of `final`.

Comment: @maaartinus: Yep, you can refer to JCiP for the exact conditions: http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=EK43StEVfJIC&pg=PT64&lpg=PT64&dq=java+concurrency+in+practice+immutable+object&source=bl&ots=uoUxD2yQlw&sig=7ZzT-gyHLTstKxJyd5TJvKVsFcg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=v9sVVN_eAdDsaOnigsAG&ved=0CF8Q6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=java%20concurrency%20in%20practice%20immutable%20object&f=false I added the excerpt in the answer

Comment: @maaartinus: the `final long` is fine as it will meet the conditions outlined in the above link

Comment: @maaartinus Effectively immutable is more like anything with a lazily computed field, for example.  Many objects are externally immutable but have mutable internal state for caching, lazy initialization, etc.

Comment: @EnnoShioji I also have question related to thread safety [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41925494/how-to-keep-retrying-block-machine-every-x-interval-until-url-is-executed-succes). I wanted to see if you can help me out?